# @gorhom/bottom-sheet - Dynamic height for children view

Tags: react-native, bottom-sheet

How to set dynamic height for the children's view by setting snap points or another way?
Here is my parent and child component code.

[image]

**Need to set dynamic height to the modal by removing extra spaces**

**child.tsx**

```
import {
 BottomSheetModal,
 BottomSheetModalProps,
 BottomSheetModalProvider,
} from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';
import { BottomSheetModalMethods } from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet/lib/typescript/types';
import { Portal } from 'react-native-portalize';    

const BottomSheet = forwardRef<BottomSheetModalMethods, Props>(
({ children, snapPoints, handleSheetClose }, ref) => {

const memorizedSnapPoints = useMemo(() => snapPoints, [snapPoints]);

return (
  <Portal>
    <BottomSheetModalProvider>
      <BottomSheetModal
        ref={ref}
        index={1}
        snapPoints={memorizedSnapPoints}
        backdropComponent={(props) => (
          <CustomBackdrop onPress={handleSheetClose} {...props} />
        )}
        handleIndicatorStyle={handler}
        onDismiss={handleSheetClose}
        backgroundStyle={backgroundModal}
      >
        <View style={[flex1, contentContainer]}>{children}</View>
      </BottomSheetModal>
    </BottomSheetModalProvider>
  </Portal>
);
},
);
```

**parent.tsx**

```
<BottomSheet
    ref={bottomSheetModalRef}
    snapPoints={['25%', DEVICE_HEIGHT * 0.35]}
    handleSheetClose={handleSheetClose}
  >
```

Comment: You need to use BottomSheetScrollView main content I solved it this way. Example here
https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet/issues/1573#issuecomment-1949313529

Answer (score 1):

There's no clean way to do this without making your component messy, but there's an [active pull request](https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet/pull/1402), so we'll probably see this feature soon.

Comment: I believe the issue has been resolved now that this pull request has been merged.

https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet/pull/1513

Answer (score 0):

You should check `enableDynamicSizing` prop ([link to the docs](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/props#enabledynamicsizing))